# When the vue-cli-service build is completed, the process will not shut down automatically

Tags: node.js, jenkins, vue-cli-3

When I used vue-cli-service to build my project, the console prompted:

```
 DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
```

The command I use is:

```
vue-cli-service build
```

However, the process will not automatically shut down.

Usually, I don't have to worry about this, but when I use tools like `jenkins`, the build process is not closed and the `jenkins` can't continue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What command did you use to build the project? Please post the full command with all parameters

Comment: Okay, I've added that.

Answer (score 1):

I had inserted this code block for hot-reloading to add a feature to the app. It however has the effect of preventing `vue-cli-service` from exiting after you build in your CI/CD.

Removing the hot-reloading config in my `vue.config.js` solved the issue
git diff:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already know the reason, because I also executed a piece of code to monitor file changes when I packaged, which made it impossible for the process to exit after packing.